How is it that Archimedes's spiral is the derivative of the unit circle w.r.t. $i$?
The unit circle in the complex plane is given by $z=e^{i\theta}$. Therefore,
$$
\frac{\partial z}{\partial i}=\theta e^{i\theta} 
$$
which is precisely Archimedes's spiral. This may be a fluke, but let's take it a step further. The Weyl Fractional Derivative formula for the exponential function is given by
$$
_{-\infty}W_x^\alpha e^{ax}=a^\alpha e^{ax}
$$
If we allow that that $x=i$ and $a=\theta$, then we have that the fractional derivative of order $\alpha$ (positive or negative) gives the complete spectrum of Archimedean spirals, to wit,
$$
D^\alpha e^{i\theta}=\theta^\alpha e^{i\theta}
$$
For example, Fermat ($\alpha=1/2$), Lituus ($\alpha=-1/2$), and Hyperbolic ($\alpha=-1$).
The concept of differentiation with respect to $i$ is not a commonly used operation in mathematical or practical applications. But it is not unheard of either. So the question is, what, if anything, is the meaning of the (fractional) derivative with respect to $i$? Is it real (no pun intended) or all just all a coincidence?

How can you derive with respect to a constant? As an example, what does $\frac{\partial z}{\partial {364}}$ mean?

@MasB As you can see, I did take a partial derivative w.r.t. a constant. There's nothing wrong with that. The surprising thing was that something meaningful came out of it. Furthermore, the fractional derivatives produce consistent results.

You could think of a function $f: \mathbb{C}^2 \to \mathbb{C}$ as $f(z,w) = e^{wz}$. Then you have that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial w} = ze^{wz}$, evaluating at $w = i$ gives the result. I don't think there is anything particularly deep here, or any insight to be gained by looking at fractional derivatives.

Of course, that's what I did here. The point is that something meaningful came out of it, where you would normally not expect anything. The point of the fractional derivatives is that a consistent pattern of behavior emerges.

What [...] is the meaning of the (fractional) derivative with respect to $i$?
Nothing really. You could say $f\left( \theta,\, \varphi \right) := e^{\theta \cdot \phi} \wedge f^{\left( \alpha \right)}\left( \theta,\, \varphi \right) := {_{-\infty}\operatorname{W}_{\varphi}^{\alpha}}\left[ f\left( \theta,\, \varphi \right) \right]$ then
$f^{\left( \alpha \right)}\left( \theta,\, i \right) = \theta^{\alpha} \cdot e^{\theta \cdot i}$. But you could also say $e^{\theta \cdot i} = \cos\left( \theta \right) + \sin\left( \theta \right) \cdot i$, so$\frac{\partial e^{\theta \cdot i}}{\partial i} = \frac{\partial \left( \cos\left( \theta \right) + \sin\left( \theta \right) \cdot i \right)}{\partial i} \implies \theta \cdot e^{\theta \cdot i} = \sin\left( \theta \right) ~\unicode{x21af}$ (wich is a contradiction, so there is no meaning). Aka it strongly depends on what you mean. If we assume the former ($g^{\left( \alpha \right)}\left( \theta,\, \varphi \right) := {_{-\infty}\operatorname{W}_{\varphi}^{\alpha}}\left[ g\left( \theta,\, \varphi \right) \right]$) then there is no deeper meaning then standard analysis (I think). You could potentially encounter this as a boundary condition for a PDE.
Is [...] all just all a coincidence?
You could explain it with the isomorphism between complex numbers and $2$D vectors: $a + b \cdot i \mapsto \begin{pmatrix} a\\ b\\ \end{pmatrix} \wedge \left\{ a,\, b \right\} \in \mathbb{R}$
So:
\begin{align*}
f\left( \theta,\, \varphi \right) := e^{\theta \cdot \phi} &\wedge f^{\left( \alpha \right)}\left( \theta,\, \varphi \right) := {_{-\infty}\operatorname{W}_{\varphi}^{\alpha}}\left[ f\left( \theta,\, \varphi \right) \right]\\
f^{\left( \alpha \right)}\left( \theta,\, i \right) = \theta^{\alpha} \cdot e^{\theta \cdot i} &= \theta^{\alpha} \cdot \cos\left( \theta \right) + \theta^{\alpha} \cdot \sin\left( \theta \right) \cdot i\\
f^{\left( \alpha \right)}\left( \theta,\, i \right) &\mapsto \begin{pmatrix} \theta^{\alpha} \cdot \cos\left( \theta \right)\\ \theta^{\alpha} \cdot \sin\left( \theta \right)\\ \end{pmatrix} \wedge \left\{ \alpha,\, \theta \right\} \in \mathbb{R}\\
\end{align*}
and $\left( \theta^{\alpha} \cdot \cos\left( \theta \right),\, \theta^{\alpha} \cdot \sin\left( \theta \right) \right)$ is just the parameter form of the spirals or circle you described. The associated polar equation would be $r = \theta^{\alpha}$. But you could also get other stuff. For example, you would get different graphs if you consider other branches when exponentiating or differentiate with complex order. You could also try non-real $\theta$ like other imaginary units (like $\varepsilon$ from the dual numbers) and you would get completely other graphs.
E.G. using other branches: We could use $\theta^{\alpha} = \left| \theta \right|^{\alpha} \cdot e^{\alpha \cdot \left( \arg\left( \theta \right) \cdot i + 2 \cdot k \cdot \pi \cdot i \right)} = \left| \theta \right|^{\alpha} \cdot e^{\left( u\left( -\theta \right) \cdot \pi + \alpha \cdot 2 \cdot k \cdot \pi \right) \cdot i}$, so
$\theta^{\alpha} \cdot e^{\theta \cdot i} = \left| \theta \right|^{\alpha} \cdot e^{\left( u\left( -\theta \right) \cdot \pi + \alpha \cdot 2 \cdot k \cdot \pi \right) \cdot i} \cdot e^{\theta \cdot i} = \left| \theta \right|^{\alpha} \cdot e^{\left( u\left( -\theta \right) \cdot \pi + \alpha \cdot 2 \cdot k \cdot \pi + \theta \right) \cdot i}$ aka
$f^{\left( \alpha \right)}\left( \theta,\, i \right) \mapsto \begin{pmatrix} \theta^{\alpha} \cdot \cos\left( u\left( -\theta \right) \cdot \pi + \alpha \cdot 2 \cdot k \cdot \pi + \theta \right)\\ \theta^{\alpha} \cdot \sin\left( u\left( -\theta \right) \cdot \pi + \alpha \cdot 2 \cdot k \cdot \pi + \theta \right)\\ \end{pmatrix} \wedge \alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ where $\theta \ne 0$ and $u\left( \cdot \right)$ is the unit step function. These are also just spirals but they a rotated by $\alpha \cdot k \cdot 360^{\circ}$. Here is a plot for $\alpha = \frac{1}{3} \wedge \theta \in \left[ 0,\, 10 \cdot \pi \right]$ and ${\color{red}{k = 0}} \vee {\color{blue}{k = 1}} \vee {\color{green}{k = 2}}$:

E.G. using complex order: Let's say $\alpha = \overbrace{x}^{\Re} + \overbrace{y}^{\Im} \cdot i \wedge \left\{ x,\, y \right\} \in \mathbb{R}$, then
\begin{align*}
\theta^{\alpha} &= e^{\ln\left( \theta^{\alpha} \right)} = e^{\alpha \cdot \ln\left( \theta \right)} = e^{\alpha \cdot \ln\left( \left| \theta \right| \cdot e^{\left( \arg\left( \theta \right) + 2 \cdot k \cdot \pi \right) \cdot i} \right)} = e^{\alpha \cdot \left( \ln\left( \left| \theta \right| \right) + \ln\left( e^{\left( \arg\left( \theta \right) + 2 \cdot k \cdot \pi \right) \cdot i} \right) \right)} = e^{\alpha \cdot \left( \ln\left( \left| \theta \right| \right) + \left( \arg\left( \theta \right) + 2 \cdot k \cdot \pi \right) \cdot i \right)}\\
\theta^{\alpha} &= e^{\left( x + y \cdot i \right) \cdot \left( \ln\left( \left| \theta \right| \right) + \left( \arg\left( \theta \right) + 2 \cdot k \cdot \pi \right) \cdot i \right)} = e^{x \cdot \left( \ln\left( \left| \theta \right| \right) + \left( \arg\left( \theta \right) + 2 \cdot k \cdot \pi \right) \cdot i \right) + y \cdot \left( \ln\left( \left| \theta \right| \right) + \left( \arg\left( \theta \right) + 2 \cdot k \cdot \pi \right) \cdot i \right) \cdot i}\\
\theta^{\alpha} &= e^{x \cdot \ln\left( \left| \theta \right| \right) - y \cdot \arg\left( \theta \right) - y \cdot 2 \cdot k \cdot \pi + \left( x \cdot \arg\left( \theta \right) + x \cdot 2 \cdot k \cdot \pi + y \cdot \ln\left( \left| \theta \right| \right) \right) \cdot i} = e^{x \cdot \ln\left( \left| \theta \right| \right) - y \cdot \arg\left( \theta \right) - y \cdot 2 \cdot k \cdot \pi} \cdot e^{\left( x \cdot \arg\left( \theta \right) + x \cdot 2 \cdot k \cdot \pi + y \cdot \ln\left( \left| \theta \right| \right) \right) \cdot i}\\
\end{align*}
thus
\begin{align*}
\theta^{\alpha} \cdot e^{\theta \cdot i} &= e^{x \cdot \ln\left( \left| \theta \right| \right) - y \cdot \arg\left( \theta \right) - y \cdot 2 \cdot k \cdot \pi} \cdot e^{\left( x \cdot \arg\left( \theta \right) + x \cdot 2 \cdot k \cdot \pi + y \cdot \ln\left( \left| \theta \right| \right) \right) \cdot i} \cdot e^{\theta \cdot i}\\
\theta^{\alpha} \cdot e^{\theta \cdot i} &= e^{x \cdot \ln\left( \left| \theta \right| \right) - y \cdot \arg\left( \theta \right) - y \cdot 2 \cdot k \cdot \pi} \cdot e^{\left( x \cdot \arg\left( \theta \right) + x \cdot 2 \cdot k \cdot \pi + y \cdot \ln\left( \left| \theta \right| \right) + \theta \right) \cdot i}\\
\theta^{\alpha} \cdot e^{\theta \cdot i} &= e^{x \cdot \ln\left( \left| \theta \right| \right) - y \cdot u\left( -\theta \right) \cdot \pi - y \cdot 2 \cdot k \cdot \pi} \cdot e^{\left( x \cdot u\left( -\theta \right) \cdot \pi + x \cdot 2 \cdot k \cdot \pi + y \cdot \ln\left( \left| \theta \right| \right) + \theta \right) \cdot i}\\
f^{\left( \alpha \right)}\left( \theta,\, i \right) &\mapsto \begin{pmatrix} e^{x \cdot \ln\left( \left| \theta \right| \right) - y \cdot u\left( -\theta \right) \cdot \pi - y \cdot 2 \cdot k \cdot \pi} \cdot \cos\left( x \cdot u\left( -\theta \right) \cdot \pi + x \cdot 2 \cdot k \cdot \pi + y \cdot \ln\left( \left| \theta \right| \right) + \theta \right)\\ e^{x \cdot \ln\left( \left| \theta \right| \right) - y \cdot u\left( -\theta \right) \cdot \pi - y \cdot 2 \cdot k \cdot \pi} \cdot \sin\left( x \cdot u\left( -\theta \right) \cdot \pi + x \cdot 2 \cdot k \cdot \pi + y \cdot \ln\left( \left| \theta \right| \right) + \theta \right)\\ \end{pmatrix}.\\
\end{align*}
We get graphs that may or may not look like spirals... Here is a plot for $k = 0 \wedge \theta \in \left( 0,\, 10 \cdot \pi \right]$ and ${\color{red}{\alpha = \frac{1}{3}}} \vee {\color{blue}{\alpha = \frac{1}{3} - i}} \vee {\color{green}{\alpha = \frac{1}{3} - 2 \cdot i}}$:

